# $\langle s \rangle \sim \langle t \rangle$ and $\langle s \rangle \cap \langle t \rangle$, where $s$ and $t$ are permutations in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory

Let $s=(12)(345)$ and $t=(123456)$ be permutations in $S_6$ how to know if $\langle s \rangle$ and $\langle t \rangle$ are isomorphic or not? Also what about $\langle s \rangle \cap \langle t \rangle$?

Do I compute down explicitly all elements of each subgroup and see if both have elements with same order? Btw in book answer is that both are isomorphic and intersection is trivial. 
Is there some general result that I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by the intersection of two permutations? I have heard of the intersection of two permutation *groups* but not of individual permutations.

Comment: Its not intersection of two permutations. But intersection of cyclic subgroups generated by each permutation.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "isomorphic". The groups $\langle s \rangle$ and $\langle t\langle$ are isomorphic as groups, but not isomorphic as permutation groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, both $s$ and $t$ are of order $6$, hence $\langle s\rangle$ and $\langle t\rangle$ are both isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. The intersection is trivial, since every permutation in $\langle s\rangle$ fixes $6$, and only trivial one in $\langle t\rangle$ fixes $6$.

Comment: How do u we know that every permutatuon in <s> fixes 6

Comment: @Foggy Since generator $s$ fixes $6$.